# Graphviz (dot) control edge routing

Tags: graphviz, dot

In this graph the bottom edge is not drawn symmetrical to the top edge:

```
digraph G {
    A:ne -> A:nw;
    A:sw -> A:se;
}
```

[image]

I want it to look more like a "fat snowman" with the edge `A:sw -> A:se;` looping below the node. Is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer no - or not easily.
Loops seem to be placed from the **rankdir** direction.  If **rankdir** is TB (down), loops seem to be placed "up".
It you're willing to work at it, you can run your graph twice, once with **rankdir=TB**, once with **rankdir=BT** - both times with **-Tdot**.  Then you'd have to replace the offending edge with the equivalent edge from the other graph.  [I hope this makes some sense]
Here is a tweaked version of your graph run with different values of rankdir:

```
digraph G {
    A:ne -> A:nw;
    A:sw -> A:se;
    dummy [style=invis]
    dummy -> A [style=invis]
}
```

[image]
[image]